# ng-fullcalendar title have undefinedundefined in angular 5

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using ng-fullcalendar in my angular 5 project.
I have used code same as mentioned in full-calendar website. 
Here is my npm versions and my code as well to have better look to my issue.

**package.json**

Here is the glimpse of my package.json file

`"fullcalendar": "^3.6.1",
"ng-fullcalendar": "^1.4.0",
"moment" : latest,`

**fullcalendar.component.html**

```
<ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)">
    </ng-fullcalendar>
```

**fullcalendar.component.ts**

```
this.valuationService.getEvents().subscribe(data => {
            this.events = data;
            this.calendarOptions = {
                editable: true,
                height: 'auto',
                eventLimit: false,
                // defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
                header: {
                    center: 'title ',
                    left: 'prev,today,next',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: []
            };
        });
```

Here is the image of the problem that I am facing so you can have better look at it.
[image]

I have followed one github demo and used same version packages and all still I am having errors of undefined undefined. I have go through all the possible solution that are given in stack ,github etc but still couldn't find it right.

Though I found one solution but for that I have to change some code in fullcandar.min.js in node_modules file. So it is not very convenient to do that.
Hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you import both fullcalendar and ng-fullcalendar? Can you try only the first one as the second is deprecated

Comment: Sorry , for that because I have go through all possible solutions so install other one and try that @Dimitrios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an version issue.

But if with higher version you will not get error on production.

In local with `ng-serve` you will get this error but with same version `ng build --prod`
this issue will be resolved.